# Check if a service is running with Win32_Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a very quick question about Win32_Service

Is

```
String sState = service["State"].ToString();
if (! sState.Equals("Running"))
```

Sufficent to moniter if a service is not running? I want the if statement to return true in all cases where the service isn't running so it can send a warning message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows service states are:

- `SERVICE_STOPPED`. Service is not running.
- `SERVICE_START_PENDING`. Service is starting (but you can assume that it is not running. Hopefully the service will start soon)
- `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING`. Service is stopping. (but you can assume that it is still running, except possibly the only thing service is doing is finishing in an orderly manner, disregarding any external request)
- `SERVICE_RUNNING`. Service is running (and ready to meet external requests)
- `SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING`. Similar to `START_PENDING`. Hopefully the service will start soon.
- `SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING`. Service is going to be paused in the near future.
- `SERVICE_PAUSED`. Service is paused

The only state that guarantees that the service is running is `SERVICE_RUNNING`, but I would not display a warning if the service is in state `START_PENDING`. At least, show different warnings depending on the state.

HTH.